# How i chaining from two view on one nib file in ios

Tags: ios, view

I have one nib file and have two view on it, i want to know how cold i change view from one to the other. 
thanks for help

Comment: do you want only one view to be visible at the moment?

Comment: something like that, i tray [view sethidden:YES]; and [view-custom setHidden:NO]; but its not worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods you should be overly familiar with:

```
[parentView addSubview:childView];
[childView removeFromSuperview];
```

You should not just be thinking in views, which are arranged in a hierarchy, but also of view controllers, which have a different but vaguely related hierarchy of their own.  Check out the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

Also, the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIView) are things you should be overly familiar with.

Comment: you may be wrong. addSubview but not addView method in UIView class

Comment: and btw, it's not necessary to invoke removeFromSuperview. it's invoked automatically within addSubview method

Comment: my intent wasn't that that was a code snippet, but two method calls you should know, in his case childView1 and childView2 might be used - correct if you add a view to a superview it's removed from its current superview if it has one

Answer (score 0):

if you have two views on other view, and they lies under each other, you may use `bringSubviewToFront` method to show desired view.
you can also use `hidden` property of UIView object to show/hide custom view:

```
//method 1
[parentView bringSubviewToFront: myView1];
//method 2
myView1.hidden=YES;
myView2.hidden=NO;
```